# Help with Generalized Drinker's Paradox: $\exists x:[D(x)\implies Q]$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic

I need help proving $\exists x:[D(x)\implies Q]$ for arbitrary unary predicate $D$ and proposition $Q$.

I think it should be possible since I have been able to prove a set-theoretic version: $\exists x: [x\in D \implies Q]$ for arbitrary set $D$ and proposition $Q$, but I don't see how to translate it into a purely FOL proof.

---

**EDIT**

On further consideration, the FOL version is clearly not true in general. Consider, for example, the case of $\forall x: D(x)$ being true and $Q$ being false.

The set-theoretic version, however, is obviously true if the universal set does not exist. Since every set would then exclude something, we must then have some $x$ such that $x\notin D$. Introducing disjunction, we have $x\notin D \lor Q$ or equivalently $x\in D \implies Q$. Generalizing, we have $\exists x:[x\in D\implies Q]$.

The two, seemingly equivalent statements are at odds with one another. Is this not a problematic?

---

**FOLLOW-UP**

It is not problematic at all. You simply have more ways to prove things, more tools with set theory. In set theory, you can construct subsets and quantify over sets. Both of these tools are essential to the resolution of the Paradox of the Universal Set, which in turn is essential to prove  $\exists x:[x\in D\implies Q]$. There is no equivalent of these tools available in FOL. This leaves  $\exists x:[D(x)\implies Q]$ unprovable in FOL.

Comment: If $Q=\bot$ then isn't that just $\exists x : \neg D(x)$? If so, then shouldn't $D(x) := \top$ contradict your statement? (This doesn't work in set theory, since such a set would be the universal set). Or do I misunderstand something?

Comment: @Ian Sorry, I don't follow your argument, but the set-theoretic proof is based on the non-existence of the universal set. Since every set must exclude something, we must have some $x$ such that $x\notin D$. Introducing disjunction, we have $x\notin D \lor Q$ or equivalently $x \in D \implies Q$. Generalizing, we have $\exists x:[x \in D \implies Q]$.

Comment: That doesn't work for predicates, for they can be always true.

Comment: @Ian Hmmmm... The FOL version is not true in general. It is false if $\forall x:D(x)$ is true and if $Q$ is false. Is this what you were getting at? The two versions are at odds with one another. Isn't this problematic? Is this Russell's Paradox for FOL?

Comment: Or does this demonstrate some inconsistency in set theory??? Must we accept the existence of a universal set? What do the experts say?

Comment: There is **no** inconsistency because the two formulae are **not** equivalent (see Addition to my answer). A theorem of set theory is provable formula in set theory; by *completeness*, it is a formula that is *true* in every model of the axioms of set theory. This does not imply that the formula is *valid*, i.e. true in **every** interpretation ...

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA I guess it makes sense that you can prove MORE things if you have more axioms, but it still bothers me that, of two such similar statements, one is provable and one is not.

Answer (score 2):

Regarding :

> $\exists x [D(x) \to Q]$ --- **(*)**

we cannot prove it in FOL, because it is not *valid*.

Consider a *false* proposition $Q$, like : $\forall y(y \ne y)$ and consider as $D(x)$ the unary *predicate* $\exists y(y = x)$.

Thus, the formula above is :

> $\exists x [\exists y(y = x) \to \forall y(y \ne y)]$

which is *false* in any not-empty domain $D$, because the conditional : $\exists y(y = x) \to \forall y(y \ne y)$ has a true *antecedent* and a false *consequent*.

---

*Added*

Your example in set theory can be rewritten as $x \in \emptyset$ as the *false* proposition $Q$ :

> $\exists x [x \in D \to x \in \emptyset]$.

But this is not the same as **(*)** above; in *first-order* set theory, all variables are *individual* variables "ranging" over the "universe" of sets and $\in$ is a binary *predicate*.

Thus, the formal counterpart of the last formula is :

> $\exists x [\in(x,d) \ \to \ \in(x,\emptyset)]$;

of course, $\in(x,\emptyset)$ is always *false*, and we can prove that $\forall y \exists x (x \notin y)$ (i.e. there is no "universal" set).

This implies :

> $\forall y \exists x [x \notin y \lor x \in \emptyset]$,

i.e.

> > $\forall y \exists x [x \in y \to x \in \emptyset]$.

In conclusion, the fact that the last formula is a *theorem* of set theory implies that it is *true* in every model of the axioms of set theory. This does not imply that the formula is *valid*, i.e. true in every interpretation.

Comment: I came to the same realization an hour before your posting. (See my comments on original.) The interesting thing now is that the set theoretic version seems to be at odds with the FOL. Is this not problematic?

Comment: I agree the FOL formula is not provable (see my edit). But I am not sure how to reconcile it with the seemingly equivalent but provable set-theoretic formula.

Comment: It's about the domain of discourse. $\exists x (x\in D \to y\in \varnothing)$ is false when $D$ is universal.  But is we deny that there can be a universal set, then it is never false.

Comment: Similarly $\exists x(D(x)\to \bot)$ is false in domains of discourse where $D(x)$ is universal but true if we discuss another domain where $D(x)$ is not universally true (eg. move from discussing $\exists x(x\geq 0 \to \bot )$ for natural numbers, to integers).

Answer (score 1):

Take the statement $\;\exists x (D(x) \to Q)\;$ where $x$ is not free in $Q$ .

$$\begin{array}{l}\exists x\;(D(x)\to Q) 
\\ \quad\Updownarrow (\text{implication equivalence}) \\
\exists x\;(\neg D(x) \vee Q )
\\ \quad\Updownarrow (\text{distribuition }\exists\text{ over }\vee) \\
\exists x\;\neg D(x) \;\vee\; \exists x\; Q
\\ \quad\Updownarrow (x \text{ is not free in }Q) \\
\exists x\; \neg D(x) \;\vee\; Q
\\ \quad\Updownarrow (\text{dual negation}) \\
\neg\forall x\; D(x)\;\vee\; Q
\\ \quad\Updownarrow (\text{implication equivalence}) \\
\big( \forall x\; D(x) \big) \;\to\; Q
\end{array}$$

Thus the statement is not a tautology.   It is *falsified* iff $D(x)$ is universally true but $Q$ is false.

For instant, if $U$ is the universal set (if we don't deny its existence), then $\exists x( x\in U \to y\in \varnothing)$ is false, while for any $A: A\subset U$, then $\exists x( x\in A\to y\in \varnothing)$ is true because $x\in A$ is not universally true for a strict subset of the universal set (by definition).

But if we do deny the existence of a universal set then the one case were the statement is false never occurs.  $\forall x(x\in D)$ is always false for any $D$.